# I am getting arbitrarily changing variables, I have a warning for "6011 dereferencing null pointer"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, null-pointer

My variables seem to change at random.  My only lead is "6011 dereferencing null pointer".  I am using C++ with allegro on MSVS.

I've tried going through the code line by line and placing break points at common problem areas.  I actually might have made it worse at one point where I changed the parameters of grabframe from taking a width and height to taking a sprite and using its width and height.  But even before the change the variables were changing randomly

in my header:

```
//define the sprite structure
typedef struct SPRITE{
    int dir, alive;
    int x, y;
    int width, height;
    int xspeed, yspeed;
    int xdelay, ydelay;
    int xcount, ycount;
    int curframe, maxframe, animdir;
    int framecount, framedelay;
}SPRITE;
SPRITE* player1spr;
BITMAP* player1[121];
```

in my C++ file that includes the main:

```
//grabframe function
//takes sprites out of a sprite sheet and stores it in bitmaps
//parameters are:
//BITMAP* source: a bitmap that holds the sprite sheet
//SPRITE* sprite: the sprite that is going to use the frame
//int startx: the start x coordinate of the sprite sheet
//int starty: the start y coordinate of the sprite sheet
//int columns: the amount of columns the sprite sheet has
//int frame the frame thats being grabbed
BITMAP* grabframe(BITMAP* source, SPRITE* sprite, int startx, int starty, int columns, int frame) {
    //create temporary bitmap to hold the sprite
    BITMAP* temp = create_bitmap(sprite->width, sprite->height);
    //find the dimensions of a sprite given the properties of the sprite      sheet
    int tempx = startx + (frame % columns) * sprite->width;
    int tempy = starty + (frame / columns) * sprite->height;
    //blit the sprite onto the sheet
    blit(source, temp, tempx, tempy, 0, 0, sprite->width, sprite->height);
    return temp;
}
```

in my main:

```
player1spr = (struct SPRITE*)malloc(sizeof(SPRITE*));
player1spr->maxframe = 121;
player1spr->curframe = 0;
player1spr->width = 600;
player1spr->height = player1spr->width;

// create a bitmap for the player one character
temp1 = (BITMAP*)data[PLAYER1_BMP].dat;
for (player1spr->curframe = 0; player1spr->curframe < player1spr->maxframe; player1spr->curframe++) {
    player1[player1spr->curframe] = grabframe(temp1, player1spr, 0, 0, 11, player1spr->curframe);
}
destroy_bitmap(temp1);
```

Errrors like this:

```
Exception thrown at 0x0F81B605 (allegro-4.4.2-monolith-md.dll) in Assignment2 v2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000010.
```

I expect my sprite variables to stay the same but they change.

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable.

Comment: Why are you using C-style casts all over the place? Using a cast (any cast) is usually a bug. Using a C-style cast, doubly so.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++ code, please. Unless you *really* know what you are doing (which I doubt), that's usually wrong.

Comment: In C++ you don't need the `typedef struct` syntax.  The `struct` and `class` define types.

Comment: `typedef struct SPRITE` - You do come from a C background, don't you? That's not how you'd do it in C++.

Comment: malloc(sizeof(SPRITE*)) - is wrong! You should allocate memory for structure, not for pointer. malloc(sizeof(SPRITE)) - is a correct way.

Comment: What are the results after you used a debugger?  Which statement is causing the issue?  What are the values of the variables that the statement uses?

Comment: The key to debugging is isolating the bug. When you've eliminated everything that isn't bug, the bug's usually pretty easy to see and prove that you've fixed it. Pick one bug and play a few rounds of divide and conquer to narrow down where that bug is. Use [mcve] as inspiration. If you're still stuck after that post the minimized program you've come up with.

Comment: @oleque Except for the fact that `malloc` is usually the wrong thing to do in C++. It doesn't call constructors. So, except for POD types, it's likely a bug.

Comment: When in Rome, do as the Romans do. When in C++, do C++ before falling back onto C.

Comment: `player1spr = new SPRITE;` fixes at least one bug. Of course this is how it should have been from the start.

Comment: Thank you for the malloc(sizeof(SPRITE)) comment (and all the comments).  I input that and quickly changed some stupid typos and now my code compiles.  Still seems like a bit of work to go but thank you all for your help :)

Comment: Stop using raw pointers and manual memory management, all these problems will go away